AWS Q Business chat_sync api issue with python boto3
I am trying to implement aws business q apis inside my own application. I am following below document provided by aws but it's not working for chat_sync function.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonq/latest/qbusiness-ug/making-sigv4-authenticated-api-calls.html#data-plane-workflow

Created temporary session using AssumeRole

sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
response = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXX:role/assume_role',
    RoleSessionName='temp_sess'
)


Setting up the session values received from step 1.
session = boto3.Session(
aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_session_token='XXXXXXXXXX'
)

aq_client = session.client(
    "qbusiness",
    region_name="us-east-1"
)

resp = aq_client.chat_sync(
    applicationId = "amazon-qbusiness-application-id",
    userMessage = "chat-request",
    clientToken = str(random.randint(0,10000)
)



getting below error message
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the ChatSync operation: User ID must be null and identity-aware credentials must be passed for identity-center enabled applications
After passsing userId as a parameter also it's not working.
I have tried all the steps mentioned in the document but error is not getting resolved. Please help with the latest codebase.
